# IP2Location record to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ip2location

I've used IP2Location to gather information on IP addresses and I want it in a DataFrame but when I tried to use `pd.json_normalize(ip)` I got an error.
`AttributeError: 'IP2LocationRecord' object has no attribute 'values'`

The information I got from IP2Location is in this format,

`{'ip': '66.249.79.244', 'country_short': 'US', 'country_long': 'United States of America', 'region': 'California', 'city': 'Mountain View', 'latitude': 37.405991, 'longitude': -122.078514, 'zipcode': '94043', 'timezone': '-08:00'}`

I have also tried to use `pd.DataFrame` but the results in the df was empty, only the column names were seen.

`df = pd.DataFrame(ip, columns = ['ip','country_short','country_long','region','city','latitude','longitude','zipcode','timezone'])`

Expected outcome

```
     ip               country_short    country_long        ....       zipcode      timezone
0    66.249.69.244    US               United States of America       94043        -08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the error:

`AttributeError: 'IP2LocationRecord' object ...`

What you are trying to do, is to convert the object of type `IP2LocationRecord` to `pandas.DataFrame` which is not directly possible (you have to directly unpack all values, or create a dictionary out of fields of `IP2LocationRecord`).
What you are seeing here :

```
{'ip': '66.249.79.244', 'country_short': 'US', 'country_long': 'United States of America', 'region': 'California', 'city': 'Mountain View', 'latitude': 37.405991, 'longitude': -122.078514, 'zipcode': '94043', 'timezone': '-08:00'}
```

is actually `repr(ip)` [**repr** python3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (and not a dictionary)